# Fold expression: Replacing specific type but forwarding all others Why are my overloads not considered for overload resolution?

Tags: c++, templates

I've trying to replace a specific type within a fold expression while simply forwarding all other types, but failed miserably.

A simulation of `std::forward`; actually copied GCC's implementation of and just added a bit of output to see what's going on:

```
namespace test
{
template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard" << std::endl;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard (r-value)" << std::endl;
    static_assert
    (
            !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
            "template argument substituting T is an lvalue reference type"
    );
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
}
```

As `std::forward` requires explicit template specialisation I tried providing another set of templated overloads for - let's say for std::string:

```
template<typename>
auto fw(std::string const& s)
{
    std::cout << "specialised (const reference): " << s << std::endl;
    return s;
}

template<typename>
auto fw(std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << "specialised (reference): " << s << std::endl;
    return s;
}

template<typename>
std::string&& fw(std::string&& s)
{
    std::cout << "specialised (r-value reference): " << s << std::endl;
    return std::move(s);
}
```

(I added one after another all interesting overloads, which didn't change the outcome, this is the final result of, any ambiguities could be solved any time by dropping one of. Placing these into a separate namespace didn't change the outcome either).

Finally my test code (actually above functions have been intended to be static private members instead, but that's another issue):

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename ... T>
    void test(T&& ... t)
    {
        using t::fw;
        using test::fw;
        ( g(fw<T>(t)), ... );
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    T&& g(T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: r-value: " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return std::move(t);
    }
    template <typename T>
    T& g(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: l-value " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int nn = 10;
    Test t;
    std::string s("daal");
    t.test(12, nn, std::string("alda"), s);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
standard
g: r-value: 12

standard
g: l-value 10

standard
g: r-value: alda

standard
g: l-value daal
```

So my overloads are not considered for overload resolution, even though I tried to explicitly `using` both specific and global (or two specific) namespaces (`using` just the global namespace works, but then I cannot forward other types; order of `using` directives didn't matter either). But why is this so?

Side note: I discovered only afterwards that after template instantiation the signatures would actually be identical, so if the overloads *would* have been considered I this should have resulted in ambiguous function calls...

Then I failed to specialise within `test` namespace for `std::strings` – this wouldn't have been an option anyway as exposing from within a header would have led to replacing the strings at locations where they shouldn't be, so [second question would be how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884093/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-how-to-corre) (please follow the link).

Provided I *could* specialise accordingly, then I could just re-implement `std::forward` within my own namespace, provide the specialisations and then use all these – leading to the final question: [How can I achieve this without re-implementing `std::forward` from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884111/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-how-to-achie) (Please follow the link).

Side note: I discovered actually not needing the variadic template thus could work with constexpr if's inside the function instead – just asking out of **curiosity** (no XY-problem – any more).

Comment: You are asking the same question twice, please delete one of them.

Comment: @Dominique Three different questions 1. *Why* is my overload not considered? With test code provided I'd expect compilation fail due to ambiguous function calls, but that was not the case. 2. How to specialise `std::forward`? 3. How to finally achieve what I tried? 1. and 3. are similar, but here I'm asking for the *reason* for failure of this attempt while 3. is concerned for an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

They are ambiguous, but you are choosing only `test::fw` by placing `using test::fw;` last.