# Fold expression: Replacing specific type but forwarding all others, how to correctly specialise `std::forward`?

Tags: c++, templates

I've trying to replace a specific type within a fold expression while simply forwarding all other types, but failed miserably.

A simulation of `std::forward`; actually copied GCC's implementation of and just added a bit of output to see what's going on:

```
namespace test
{

template<typename T>
T&& fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard" << std::endl;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template<typename T>
T&& fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard (r-value)" << std::endl;
    static_assert
    (
            !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
            "template argument substituting T is an lvalue reference type"
    );
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

}
```

As `std::forward` requires explicit template specialisation I tried providing another set of templated overloads for, but these [haven't been considered for overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884077/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-why-are-my-ov) and would, if that had worked, have led to ambiguous function calls anyway.

So I tried specialising the forwarding templates (well aware that specialising `std::forward` itself would, as in a header, have lead to replacements where they shouldn't occur) – let's say for `std::string`. Still, out of pure **curiosity** (I discovered actually not needing the variadic template thus could work with constexpr if's inside the function instead, so no XY-problem – any more), how would I do so?

This attempt, trying to give an overload for every possible reference type (ambiguities might be solved by dropping one of) failed miserably:

```
namespace test
{

template<>
std::string const& fw<std::string const>(std::string const& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised const" << std::endl;
    return t;
}
#if 0
template<>
std::string& fw<std::string>(std::string& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised non-const" << std::endl;
    return t;
}
#endif

template<>
std::string && fw<std::string>(std::string&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised r-value" << std::endl;
    return std::move(t);
}

}
```

Test code for:

```
int main()
{
    test::fw<int>(7);
    int n;
    test::fw<int>(n);
    test::fw<std::string>(std::string("alda"));
    std::string s("daal");
    test::fw<std::string>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

should provide output

```
standard
standard
specialised r-value
specialised non-const
```

Just one single overload for l-value references would be just as fine.

Instead compilation fails with error

```
<source>:27:20: error: template-id 'fw<const std::string>' for 'const std::string& test::fw(const std::string&)' does not match any template declaration
   27 | std::string const& fw<std::string const>(std::string const& t) noexcept
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:5: note: candidates are: 'template<class T> T&& test::fw(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&)'
   15 | T&& fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
      |     ^~
<source>:8:5: note:                 'template<class T> T&& test::fw(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&)'
    8 | T&& fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
      |     ^~
```

Template declaration doesn't match (see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oWc31h5Y6) as well) – obviously only for the l-value reference overload, though, but I cannot tell why, as there is a generic overload for `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&`.

Provided I *could* specialise accordingly, then I could just re-implement `std::forward` within my own namespace, provide the specialisations and then use all these – leading to the final question: [How can I achieve this without re-implementing `std::forward` from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884111/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-how-to-achie) (Please follow the link).

Comment: You are explaining your attempted solution, rather than the actual problem you are trying to solve - a classical case of [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the ultimate goal of the exercise? Show an example of "replacing specific type but forwarding all others" - skip implementation details, describe the desired outcome.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No XY problem any more, the actually issue has been solved already, this question is just out of pure curiosity, as written already. Anyway, intention comes with linked questions..

Comment: Do note that since C++20 you cannot specialize function templates in the standard library.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hm, OK, illegal in C++ 20 – any reason why? And before?

Comment: @Aconcagua See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo/52760860#52760860

Comment: Can you show an [mcve], then? I'm still not sure I understand what you are trying to do; it's quite possible I'm just being dense. I see what you did, but I don't see what for.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Edited. Just trying to specialise `std::forward` for one specific type – out of pure curiosity, no specific use case for. Arose from *playing around* with the matter of the linked questions though clear that I wouldn't specialise `std::forward` directly. Just want to know how to do it correctly (before C++20...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be noted in advance: This attempt is entirely illegal since C++ 20 and illegal for the given use case (replacing `std::string`) as well as template specialisations for standard types have been illegal even before C++20 (thanks [@Nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72903092/1312382) for the hint and [reference to the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#1)).

Note, too, that even for custom types (before C++20) there are better approaches to replace one specific type (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885119/1312382)), so this approach should not be followed anyway (I personally only attempted to complete it out of curiosity).

The actual problem (that I missed) is that in template argument deduction in case of l-value references `T` is decuced to a *reference* type. Thus for l-value references the template parameter must be turned into a reference as well:

```
template<>
std::string const& fw<std::string const&>(std::string const& t) noexcept;
//                                     ^ (!)
template<>
std::string& fw<std::string&>(std::string& t) noexcept;
//                         ^ (!)
```

Et voilà, code compiles and for the test code as presented prints the desired output **provided** one selects the appropriate overloads as well:

```
    int n = 7;
    test::fw<int&>(n);
    //          ^ (!)
    std::string s("alda");
    test::fw<std::string&>(s); // alternatively const overload
    //                  ^ (!)
```

An interesting fact is that these overloads *apparently* don't seem to work within the following demo:

```
template <typename ... T>
void demo(T&&... t)
{
    using test::fw;
    ( fw<T>(t), ... );
    std::cout << std::endl;
    ( fw<T>(std::forward<T>(t)), ... );
}
```

prints

```
standard l-value
standard l-value
standard l-value
specialised non-const

standard r-value
standard l-value
specialised r-value
specialised non-const
```

seeming to require another `std::forward` – but in fact, all function arguments within `demo` *are* indeed l-values and thus the standard version *needs* to be called. In case of r-values `T` is deduced to non-reference, though, and resulting return type gets `T&&`, i. e. the r-value reference just as desired. However the standard version getting called for r-value `std::string` reveals that for replacing that type entirely one overload is yet lacking:

```
template<>
std::string&& fw<std::string>(std::string& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised r-value" << std::endl;
    return std::move(t);
}
```

While the r-value reference overload remains valid for cases where an intermediate function call returns such one (like the `std::forward` in second test call).

Answer (score 2):

If you must add specializations for standard template functions before C++20, just add them into `namespace std`.

According to [[namespace.std]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#1), only **user-defined classes** are allowed.

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

If you want to add a specialization of `std::string` for `std::forward`, it's undefined. You have to make your own `forward` function.

```cpp
namespace test
{

// primary template for l-value argument
template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard" << std::endl;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

// specialization for T = std::string&
template <>
std::string& forward(std::string& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised l-value" << std::endl;
    return t;
}

// specialization for T = std::string
template <>
std::string&& forward(std::string& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised r-value" << std::endl;
    return std::move(t);
}

// primary template for r-value argument
template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard (r-value)" << std::endl;
    static_assert
    (
            !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
            "template argument substituting T is an lvalue reference type"
    );
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

// primary template for r-value argument
template <>
std::string&& forward(std::string&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "specialised r-value" << std::endl;
    return std::move(t);
}

}
```

This code is also legal in C++20. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zoooETn8G)

---

If you want to add self-defined class specializations, do like this.

```cpp
struct A {};
namespace std {
template<>
A&& forward(A& a) noexcept {
    return std::move(a);
}

template<>
A& forward(A& a) noexcept {
    return a;
}
}
```

---

Adding specializations for standard template functions is disabled since C++20. And it's not recommended to do so even before C++20. The reason is sensible, for more reading see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo/52760860#52760860)

Comment: Missed that I would have tried specialising for a standard type – thanks for the hint. I'm aware how to specialise usually – what I missed, though, was that in the case of l-values T is deduced to be a *reference* thus my explicit non-templates don't match, need to be references as well... Your answer doesn't point out that – still it gave me the appropriate hints by you simply leaving out the template arguments, so still thanks ;)