# Fold expression: Replacing specific type but forwarding all others: How to achieve this?

Tags: c++, templates

I've trying to replace a specific type within a fold expression while simply forwarding all other types, but failed miserably.

As `std::forward` requires explicit template specialisation I tried providing another set of templated overloads for, but these [haven't been considered for overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884077/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-why-are-my-ov) and would, if that had worked, have led to ambiguous function calls anyway.

Second attempt was [specialising `std::forward`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884093/fold-expression-replacing-specific-type-but-forwarding-all-others-how-to-corre) but already failed in the attempt...

A simulation of `std::forward`; actually copied GCC's implementation of and just added a bit of output to see what's going on:

```
namespace test
{
template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard" << std::endl;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T&&
fw(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "standard (r-value)" << std::endl;
    static_assert
    (
            !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
            "template argument substituting T is an lvalue reference type"
    );
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
}
```

My test is as follows:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename ... T>
    void test(T&& ... t)
    {
        using test::fw;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ( g(fw<T>(t)), ... );
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    T&& g(T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: r-value: " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return std::move(t);
    }
    template <typename T>
    T& g(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: l-value " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int nn = 10;
    Test t;
    std::string s("daal");
    t.test(12, nn, std::string("alda"), s);

    return 0;
}
```

As is (and with my failed attempts, see linked questions) the output is:

```
standard
g: r-value: 12

standard
g: l-value 10

standard
g: r-value: alda

standard
g: l-value daal
```

Desired output would be something like:

```
standard
g: r-value: 12

standard
g: l-value 10

specialised (r-value)
g: r-value: alda

specialised (l-value)
g: l-value daal
```

(Reference type is optional.)

How could I achieve this?

Intention is to retain the fold-expression – I *could* solve the issue with *recursive* templates and appropriate overloads, but that's not the intention here. This is a question out of pure curiosity as I already solved my actual problem already (by discovering actually not needing the variadic template at all thus could work with `if constexpr` inside the function instead, and thus no XY-problem either – any more).

Comment: What is wrong with `std::is_same_v<T, Type1> ? specific() : generic()`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is. You can detect the type with `if constexpr` and `std::is_same_v` inside the `fw` implementation, no?

Comment: @lorro The fact that `specific` and `generic` would need to return different types?

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, that's a **good** idea, but would still require to re-implement a specific version `std::forward`, which I'd like to avoid (and I would rather go with a recursive template instead then – and there I'd certainly use that). Note, though, that my intention is to retain the fold expression, and again, just a question out of curiosity...

Comment: @Aconcagua You can also just wrap `std::forward` with the added behavior via `if constexpr` or use a lambda with `if constexpr` directly in the fold expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if constexpr` within a wrapper is the key to the solution (thanks @[user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522) for the hint), however it needs to be combined with a second `std::forward` and for not receiving only r-value[s| references] `decltype(auto)` as well. Such a function can even be included within the Test class, additionally desired but optional feature (a lambda within the test function might look like...).

A solution might look like:

```
class Test
{
    template <typename T>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// note: decltype(auto)!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    static decltype(auto) fw(T&& t)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, std::string>)
        {
            std::cout << "std::string: ";
            if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(t)>)
            {
                std::cout << "l-value\n";
                std::string s;
                s.reserve(t.length() + 2);
                s += '\'';
                s += t;
                s += '\'';
                return s;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "r-value\n";
                t.reserve(t.length() + 2);
                t.insert(t.begin(), '\'');
                t.push_back('\'');
                return t;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "default\n";
            return std::forward<T>(t);
        }
    }

public:
    template <typename ... T>
    void test(T&& ... t)
    {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// note: yet another call to std::forward!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ( g(fw(std::forward<T>(t))), ... );
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    T&& g(T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: r-value: " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return std::move(t);
    }
    template <typename T>
    T& g(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "g: l-value " << t << '\n' << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    Test t;
    std::string s("daal");
    t.test(12, n, std::string("alda"), s);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(Modifying the strings simulates conversion to another type...)

Received output (as desired):

```
default
g: r-value: 12

default
g: l-value 10

std::string: r-value
g: l-value 'alda'

std::string: l-value
g: r-value: 'daal'
```

(`auto` instead of `decltype(auto)` prints `g: r-value` four times!)